# How to make Creating prefabs with a for loop in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-editor

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, position.width, 40), "Instantiate Prefab"))
{
Selection.activeObject = PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(Selection.activeObject as GameObject);
}
```

There is such a code. As much as I want to use a loop How can I create a prefab?

(I used google translate. I'm sorry if I'm wrong).

I haven't tried using a for loop but I couldn't.